# Create bearer authorization header in OkHttp java

Tags: java, okhttp

I need to use **OkHttp3** in java as a HTTP client and send Authorization header in request.

example:

> Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRaswczovL2F1dGgucGF4aW11bS5djb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5wYXhpbXVtLmNvbSIsIm5iZiI6MTQ0ODQzNzkyMCwiZXhwIjoxNDQ4NDgxMTIwLCJzdWIiOiIzNzExZDk1YS03MWU1LTRjM2ItOWQ1YS03ZmY3MGI0NDgwYWMiLCJyb2xlIjoicGF4OmIyYjphcHA6dXNlciJ9.YR8Gs7RVM-q5AxtHpeOl2zYe-zKxh5u39TUeTbiZL1k

how can I create this token using my username and password?
username: test
password: test

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

```
  private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  private final String url = "http://test.com";

  public void run(String token) throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    //This adds the token to the header.
    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    .build();
     try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
          if (!response.isSuccessful()){
             throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
          }

         System.out.println("Server: " + response.header("anykey"));

     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Thankgod, there is a Java class named Credentials in OkHttp3 library . it creates basic Authorization from username and password.  how can I create token from username and password?

Comment: Be careful. It should be `.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+ token)`, otherwise you get "IllegalArgumentException: unexpected char 0x20 in header name".

Answer (score 9):

The above answer lead to correct path but need some changes.

```
private  Response requestBuilderWithBearerToken(String userToken) throws IOException {
           OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
           Request request = new Request.Builder()
                   .url(YourURL)
                   .get()
                   .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                   .addHeader("Authorization" , "Bearer " + userToken)
                   .build();

           return  client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: this code works for me, unlike the marked answer it gives me "Unauthorized token"

Answer (score 0):

For android Okhttp Version

```java
public Call post(String url, String json, Callback callback, String token) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}
```

remember to put space after Bearer keyword.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. For future reference, in order to improve the quality of your answer for others who may look view it, it's always good to add code comments explaining what your code is doing.