# How does one make Oauth2.0 work with a nologin msgraph (Sharepoint) client?

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, okhttp

Here are the program imports.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.microsoft.graph.auth.confidentialClient.ClientCredentialProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.auth.enums.NationalCloud;
import com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.HttpClients;
import okhttp3.*;
```

The program invokes the ClientCredentialProvider constructor to create an authProvider.

```
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(...);
```

The program creates a client to send a post request to the server to get an access token.

```
OkHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault( authProvider );
```

A subroutine uses the access token in a get request in an effort to obtain a site ID.

```
        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(target)
                .header("Authorization",
                        "Bearer " + tokenResponse.get_access_token())
                .get()
                .build();
```

Here is the code that transmits the get request.

```
response = client.newCall( request ).execute();
```

Here is the result that comes back from the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

When I manually send the get request from Postman or Charles, it works fine.

When I look at the outgoing request just before it is sent, I find that the okhttp3 code has tacked on a few more headers including a second Authorization header that uses a slightly different token.

How should the program configure okhttp3 classes to stop this interception and rewriting of the header section of the outgoing request?

Comment: Why are you manually adding the Authorization header? I would expect OkHttpClient to be handling that automatically.

Comment: I found examples of adding OAuth2 Authentication header on [this webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463607/create-bearer-authorization-header-in-okhttp-java). The example code does not work in the context of msgraph SDK, which seems to add its own interceptors. I can add my own interceptor to get around the issue. Such action seems kludgey.

Comment: The SDK doesn't handle AUTH itself. The traditional way of handling the auth size would be using https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android-msa-auth-for-android-adapter

Comment: I looked in more detail. The Microsoft Graph SDK seems to be assuming non-Sharepoint Oauth2 procedures (maybe OneDrive). When I am an interceptor to override the Sharepoint Oauth2 procedures and implement the correct procedure in this interceptor, I don't have to manually add the Authorization header. I suppose this extra work for the developer becomes necessary when a preview SDK is being used.

Comment: The Microsoft Graph SDK according to the documentation consists of three JARs.

Here are the artifactIds from my pom.xml: (1) <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>, (2) <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>, and (3) <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>. The Android authorization code is interesting but does not really address the problem with which I am dealing.

Comment: BTW, the msgraph-sdk-java-auth-all-1.0.jar in the official repository seemed broken in some way. I had to build it myself and install it in my local repository to make my programs build correctly and run properly.

Comment: Just to clarify, there isn't a SharePoint OAuth2 procedure. All tokens are generated by AAD, not the API you're calling. The only difference between tokens will be if they're using the v1 or v2 endpoint and which scopes/permissions are requested/assigned.

Comment: I may not fully understand all the aspects of authentication logic that is part of the MS Graph SDK, but this SDK is supposed to work with Sharepoint when the Client does no login authentication with OAuth2. To get this SDK to work with Sharepoint, I had to add an okhttp3 interceptor to remove the "Authorization" header that was automatically generated. Then my interceptor added an Authorization header that used the access-token expected by Sharepoint site, whose files my client application was using.

Comment: The Graph SDK doesn't handle authentication at all, that is handled by AAD (typically via the ADAL or MSAL library). It is only for talking to the Microsoft Graph APIs, all of which _do_ require an access token (authentication).

Comment: The Microsoft Graph API configures fields within the class ClientCredentialProvider. The builder seems to set fields incorrectly for Sharepoint even if it works for OneDriver. I will repose the question with more specifics.

Comment: Again, the Graph SDK is _only_ for speaking to the Microsoft Graph APIs. It is not intended to be used with legacy APIs like SharePoint's REST API.

Comment: Here is a Microsoft web page that discusses using the Graph SDK for Sharepoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I understand that. My point was that the old _SharePoint REST API_ is not the same as Microsoft Graph. The Graph SDK is only intended for talking to `graph.microsoft.com`. There are no SharePoint specific OAuth procedures for talking to Graph, you simply request all the scopes you need when you request the token.